# How can I deserialize a JSON string into a class with a variable having a different type?

Tags: c#

I used the following class to create JSON:

```
public class Detail
{
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
    public bool Response { get; set; }
    public HtmlText Text { get; set; }
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
    public HtmlText Explanation { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to deserialize this into:

```
public class Answer
{  
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
    public bool Response { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
}
```

To do this I have the following:

```
public static string ToJSONString(this object obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of my data:

```
[
  {"Correct":false,
   "Explanation":{"TextWithHtml":null},
   "ImageFile":null,
   "Response":false,
   "Text":{"TextWithHtml":"-1 1 -16 4"}
  },
  {"Correct":false,
   "Explanation":{"TextWithHtml":null},
   "ImageFile":null,
   "Response":false,
   "Text":{"TextWithHtml":"1 -1 -4 16"}
  },
  {"Correct":false,
   "Explanation":{"TextWithHtml":null},
   "ImageFile":null,
   "Response":false,
   "Text":{"TextWithHtml":"1 -1 4 2147483644"}
  }]
```

and my code:

```
IList<Answer> answers = JSON.FromJSONString<List<Answer>>(detailsJSON)
```

It's giving me an error message saying:

```
{"There was an error deserializing the object of type 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Answer, Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. 
End element 'Explanation' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'TextWithHtml' from namespace ''."} 
System.Exception {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}
```

Is there an easy way that I can change this so it will place the HtmlText into a normal string?

Comment: I think there is no direct way. You can register a custom converter to do that, you can find the explanations you need here :

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_CustomCreationConverter_1.htm and a code sample here : http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to try my suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple adjustment would be to use dictionaries like this:

```
public class Answer
{
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
    public bool Response { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Text { get; set; }
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Explanation { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize and access the values like this;

```
var answers =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Answer>>(detailsJSON);

foreach (var answer in answers)
{
  Console.WriteLine(answer.Text["TextWithHtml"]);
  Console.WriteLine(answer.Explanation["TextWithHtml"]);
}
```